# Server not properly receiving POST request from ASIFormDataRequest in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, post, asiformdatarequest

I'm trying to use an ASIFormDataRequest in my iPhone application to send a video I have just recorded to a server, along with a string that I can use to ID who the video belongs to. The code for doing so is here:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSURL *urlvideo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *urlString=[urlvideo path];
    NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/videodata.php"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSData *patientData = [_patientCode dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setFile:urlString forKey:@"video"];
    [request setData:patientData forKey:@"patientcode"];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSLog(@"responseStatusCode: %i",[request responseStatusCode]);
    NSLog(@"responseString: %@",[request responseString]);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everything seems to work correctly, I get back a status code of 200 and the method finishes as expected. However, nothing seems to be received by the php file on the server. I added this line to my server-side php code:

`echo(count($_POST));`

This returns 0, so it seems as though nothing is actually getting posted by the ASIFormDataRequest. I feel like there might be some simple step I am missing as I have never used the ASIFormDataRequest before, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I changed the `setData:patientData` to `setPostValue:_patientCode` and now that part of the post is getting sent correctly, so it seems as though `setPostValue` works but `setData` and `setFile` do not.

Comment: I know it wasn't what you asked, but you really should be thinking about using AFNetworking instead of ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer while reading something else and noticing that they did something interesting: The file I uploaded was simply going into the `$_FILES` array, not the `$_POST` array. I also changed `[request setData:patientData forKey:@"patientcode"];` to `[request setPostValue:_patientCode forKey:@"patientCode"];` and then that appeared in the `$_POST` array as I wanted so I was able to get both the string I was sending and the file I was sending in my php script.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-addData:forKey:` and `-addFile:forKey:` instead of `-setData:forKey:` and `-setFile:forKey:`.

Other than that, check the debug output when you compile with `DEBUG_FORM_DATA_REQUEST`.

You should be sending a `multipart/form-data` request when using `-addFile:forKey:` and a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request when using `-addPostValue:forKey:`.

Does your server handle `multipart/form-data` requests?